# Customizing Wordpress Pagination Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, pagination, permalinks

I have a long blog page in my blog which I split using:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

and I do see the pages split nicely such as the following pages:

```
http://www.example.com/sample_page/
http://www.example.com/sample_page/2
http://www.example.com/sample_page/3
http://www.example.com/sample_page/4
```

etc.

I want to change these pagination URLs to the following format.

```
http://www.example.com/sample_page/
http://www.example.com/sample_page/more2.html
http://www.example.com/sample_page/more3.html
http://www.example.com/sample_page/more4.html
```

etc.

I'm using Genesis theme framework. Can you please provide me some guidance on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I couldn't make it work after a lot of retries.  This is what I did via writing a function but it didn't seem to get fired at all.  Does anyone know why?

```
add_filter('get_pagenum_link', 'override_pagenum_link', 5);

function override_pagenum_link( $link )
{
   $patterns = array();
   $patterns[0] = '/(\d+)/';

   $replacements = array();
   $replacements[0] = 'more$1.htm';

   return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $link);
}
```

Anyways due to time-constraints, I went with .htaccess redirect construct to make the job done.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/more(.*).htm /$1/$2
```

If anyone has an idea on how to make the custom pagination permalinks work within Wordpress itself, I would appreciate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

default query:

`<?php $args = array(
    'base'         => '%_%',
    'format'       => '?page=%#%',
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => 0,
    'show_all'     => False,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 2,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'plain',
    'add_args'     => False,
    'add_fragment' => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number' => ''
); ?>`

You need edit **format**

(string) (optional) Used for Pagination structure. The default value is '?page=%#%', If using pretty permalinks this would be `'/page/%#%'`, where the `'%#%'` is replaced by the page number.

Default: `'?page=%#%'`

You can see that here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried to add a filter to paginate_links but it doesn't seem to work.

add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'override_page_links');
function override_page_links( $link )
{
 $defaults = array(
                  'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                  'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
                  'format' => 'page/more%#%.html'
  );
 
  return $defaults;
}

Can you please review and comment?

Comment: Are you try without **.html** ?

Comment: Yes, tried that too.  It seems like this function is never getting fired.  Any other suggestion?  I have been googling for the past 4 hours but no luck yet.

Comment: do you try add  `<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>` then paste args from my top comment and edit `'format' => '?more=%#%',`

Comment: Sorry.  Where do I add this echo statement to?

Comment: On place where you need pagination, or you can edit `function.php`